# Advanced Forms in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, forms

I am looking to create a form in Word where the value selected in a combo box will determine the text in another section of the form.

First, if I create a Combo Box in a Word document, how do I reference that Combo Box in VBA?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Properties control, set a unique value on the TAG.

[image]

Then in your VBA do something like ...

```
Dim cc As ContentControl
For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If cc.Tag = "MyCombo" Then
        'then check the value
        If cc.Range.Text = "Do Wah Diddy Diddy" Then
            'do something
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Should this code be under a specific module and sub routine like ComboBox1_Change?

Comment: @dreamerboy if you want to take immediate action when a selection is made, that requires a special subroutine added to the "ThisDocument" class of the template or document. I will add another separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking immediate action when the end user selects an item from you Content Control combo box, then you need a Private Sub in the ThisDocument class.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
```

And in it you can add a Select Case method to exam the Content Control's Tag and take action. This is an example from one of my apps.

```
Select Case ContentControl.Tag
    'Cognitive domain
    Case "LDT_L1"
        For r = 0 To UBound(AchKnowledgeArray)
            If ContentControl.Range.Text = AchKnowledgeArray(r) Then
                r = r + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
```